# CloudFront distribution invalidation with status deployed returns old version

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront

S3 contains my index.html and serves the file by static webhosting. The index.html gets a custom cache header: Cache-Control : max-age=10000, public.

CloudFront has a distribution that points to my S3 index.html. The default behavior for Object Caching is untouched: Use Origin Cache Headers.

After deploying a new version, S3 provides the new version. CloudFronts delivers a cached version, as expected. After a invalidation and some patience the CloudFront distribution has the status Deployed again. Instead of a new version CloudFront provides again the old cached version.

I am using Chrome, with developers tools open en cache disabled. Does anybody know how to force CloudFront to provide a fresh version?

**UPDATE**
Surprise, surprise: The cache control header of the index.html was manually set. After uploading a new index.html, S3 sets the default cache header to: max-age=63072000, public.

Further, I changed Object Caching to Customize with low TTL values, for testing. Now CloudFront takes a fresh version every minute. Next step is to get the invalidation working.

Comment: S3 doesn't set cache-control headers by default.  This must be something your tool is doing.